# Why doesn't VScode remember the saved state of your file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just started using vscode but I can't believe such a useful feature was overlooked. I always accidently press random buttons in files i'm not working in and it prompts the dot to save the file.. In atom, I just remove those characters and the blue dot prompting a save is gone because it remembers the last saved state. In the case of vscode removing those typos doesnt change anything and it keeps me wondering if there are other changes that i've made which i'm not aware of.

please tell me this is a setting which can be turned on.

edit:
issue if anyone wants to follow or +1

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42310

Comment: It probably has to do with the way that atom stores the current state; I think they save diffs off of the saved state in memory rather than the current state. I, too, would like to see this capability, though.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte you're right.. github issue is in the edit if you want to push for this feature

Comment: Something that may help is the "Compare Active File with Saved" command (Cmd-K D on Mac) -- it will show you a diff of the active editor with what's saved to disk.